# Problem with strings longer than 15 characters in MinGW

Tags: c++, string, mingw, getline

### Problem describe

I have a problem with `std::getline()` function. I use it like this:

```
std::fstream f; // opened in read in text mode
std::string name;
std::getline(f, name);
```

Everything works good for file with short text inside, f.e.:

```
example text
```

But when I try to read something longer, f.e.:

```
example text in file longer than 15
```

I get (after compiling and running):

```
delete: invalid pointer 00FD7A48 (0040CD22)
*** Checking for memory corruption: START
*** Checking for memory corruption: 0 FOUND
```

### Files

main.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include "plik.h"
#include "prowadzacy.h"

using namesapce std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc == 3 && !strcmp(argv[1], "-f")) {
        Prowadzacy* baza = nullptr;
        string fn(argv[2]);
        czytajZPliku(fn, baza);
    }
}
```

prowadzacy.h:

```
#include "przedmiot.h"

struct Prowadzacy {
    std::string imie;
    std::string nazwisko;

    Przedmiot* przedmiot = nullptr;

    Prowadzacy* next = nullptr;
};
```

przedmiot.h:

```
struct Przedmiot {
    std::string nazwa;
    enum Rodzaj {
        WYKLAD, CWICZENIA, LABORATORIUM, PROJEKT, SEMINARIUM
    } rodzaj;
    enum DzienTygodnia {
        PONIEDZIALEK, WTOREK, SRODA, CZWARTEK, PIATEK, SOBOTA, NIEDZIELA
    } dzien_tygodnia;
    int godzina;
    int czas_trwania;
    std::string miejsce;

    Przedmiot* next = nullptr;
};
```

plik.h:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "prowadzacy.h"
#include "przedmiot.h"

bool zapiszDoPliku (const std::string, Prowadzacy*&);
bool czytajZPliku (const std::string, Prowadzacy*&);
```

plik.cpp:

```
using namespace std;

bool czytajZPliku (const string fn, Prowadzacy*& baza) {
    fstream f;
    f.open(fn, ios::in);
    if (f) {
        string typ;
        Prowadzacy* p = baza;

        while (getline(f, typ, ' ')) {
            cout << typ << endl;
            if (typ.find("[prowadzacy]") != string::npos) {
                string imie, nazwisko;
                while (p != nullptr)
                    p = p->next;
                getline(f, imie, ',');
                getline(f, nazwisko);
                dodajProwadzacego(imie, nazwisko, baza);
            } else if (typ.find("[przedmiot]") != string::npos) {
                string nazwa;
                getline(f, nazwa);
            }
        }
        f.close();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

file with data I need to get:

```
[prowadzacy] Jan,Nowak
[przedmiot] Informatyka w Technologii
```

I use Makefile and MinGW. Compile with flags `-std=c++14 -O3 -g -pedantic-errors`

### Problem update

I write simple new program:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main () {
    std::string str = "123456789012345";
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have no trouble compiling and running these. But when I change its code to:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main () {
    std::string str = "1234567890123456";
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
1234567890123456
delete: invalid pointer 00F27F48 (004157B0)
*** Checking for memory corruption: START
*** Checking for memory corruption: 0 FOUND
```

In Visual Studio everything works fine. Why in MinGW it doesn't work?

Compile with:
`g++ -std=c++14 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -O3 -g -pedantic-errors -o main main.cpp`

Update: I tested this on Linux too. On Linux everything is fine. Problem is only in MinGW on Windows.

### Solution

Adding `-std=c++14` into compillation command fix this problem.

Comment: Strings in C++ are `std::string`. Use that instead of C-style strings.

Comment: I want to use `std::string` but this gets me errror what I described.

Comment: Please improve so [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53943436/edit) your question to show some [MCVE]

Comment: Please **edit again to give an [MCVE]** (and that means a *complete* program with a `main`, and show the command to compile it, and the input file example). Probably you have some bug *elsewhere*

Comment: I omitted some source files or functions because they're close to empty. Is this good now?

Comment: One more thing: I added `cout << nazwa;` after getline and I see all text in console window. But after that I get error what I described.

Comment: Please improve your code to be *complete* and please use English-looking names in your code (that helps a lot to understand what you want to do). Also tell us what you have understood by using your debugger. BTW, you'll better compile with `-Og` or `-O0` instead of `-O3` when you are debugging your program

Comment: Your don't show the code of `dodajProwadzacego` and your bug could be there... Again, please show a *complete* code (since it should be a [MCVE]). Your problem is *not* in `getline` (so your title is wrong) !

Comment: This function is empty yet.
There is no problem with my code I think now. I copied all sources and paste it into visual studio project and what? Everything works fine. So what's wrong with MinGW?

Comment: "There is no problem with my code I think now. " Wrong assumption: **there is a problem in *your* code**. You should trust your compiler much more than your own code. Very probably, MinGW and its [C++ standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library) is behaving as specified. BTW, you could install a [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) on your computer and debug and test your program on Linux. On Linux, you have [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) which would help you to find *your* bug

Comment: I will change my question in few minutes. Look at this please

Comment: Notice that StackOverflow is *not* a *do-my-homework* or *debug-my-code* site. You'll better delete your question and debug your own code. Maybe ask (in the future) a better question, with a [MCVE], next time. But I am sure that **the bug is in *your own* code** (not in your compiler or its C++ standard library). It is *very unlikely* that you found a genuine bug in MinGW (since that compiler is *very well tested*, much more than your own code)

Comment: Please look at "Problem update" section, maybe this will help resolving problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) related [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function (from [`<string>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string) standard header) e.g.

```
std::string linstr;
std::getline (std::cin, linstr);
```

Avoid using raw `char*` buffers.

Be also aware that [UTF-8 is used everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) in 2018 (and you can expect your users to configure their system to use UTF-8; or you should handle other [character encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)).

At last, your program could have (and probably has) some bug (e.g. some [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)) elsewhere. Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Compile with all warnings and debug info (so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)). Use the [`gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) and [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/).

### update

> when I change its code to:
>
> ```
> #include <string>
> #include <iostream>
> int main () {
>    std::string str = "1234567890123456";
>    std::cout << str << std::endl;
>    return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> I get *invalid pointer*

Probably, **you have something wrong on your computer** (the above code is perfectly legitimate C++11). I guess that you have mis-installed MinGW, or some wrong setting (e.g. `PATH` or something else) or configuration. To get more help; you need to explain a lot more it.

FYI, your last code is (of course) working perfectly on my Linux distribution (Debian/Sid, GCC 8.2). I recommend installing and using some Linux distribution, in particular because it is more developer friendly (and provides `valgrind`, which is *very* useful to hunt bugs)

Comment: I wish your last sentence was true.  It isn't.  Most Windows machines will use the system defined codepage which is almost certainly not UTF-8.

Comment: But as far as I know you can configure your Windows system to use UTF-8

Comment: You can.  But your customer probably won't (and it is a system configuration, not a program configuration).

Comment: I have:
`fstream f;`
`string name;`
`getline (f, name);`

But I get memory corruption and invalid pointer errors.

Comment: @blahax2g: Show an [MCVE] in your question.

Comment: I added `-Wall -Wextra -g` to my compile command. 0 additional errors.

Comment: Is it possible that `getline()` set stream to bad bit if text what I want to get is longer than 15 chars?

Comment: Yes, tested, on Linux works fine too. Problem is only with MinGW on Windows.

Comment: That only means that your MinGW (or your entire Windows system) is misconfigured. BTW, why don't you use Linux for your homework?

Comment: Good question... School wants to get code compatible with VS. So I use Windows but with MinGW, because I don't like VS IDE. And that sad for me too.

Comment: If VS is C++11 compliant, you just have to write code which is conforming to C++. And you could even use Linux for that. Once your code is complete, has been debugged and tested (perhaps just on Linux), you just check that it is running with VS. This is the advantage of *standards* (like C++11, e.g. [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)...)